Installing gcc13 and g++13 in Debian bookworm rust docker image
I am trying to install gcc13 and g++13 in the following Rust docker image.
# Builder
FROM rust:1-bookworm AS builder

RUN apt update
RUN apt install software-properties-common -y
RUN apt-get install python3-launchpadlib -y
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test -y
RUN apt update
RUN apt install -y clang g++-13 gcc-13

Since gcc13 is not natively available in debian bookworm, I already tried using method like using ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test as describe here.
However, I'm still getting the error E: Unable to locate package g++-13 and E: Unable to locate package g++-13. Any ideas what I have done wrong?

Is there a particular reason you need those specific versions of GCC?  Most code should compile just fine with the version of GCC in bookworm.  It may be easier to make a small change to your source code if that's necessary rather than try to install a whole new compiler.

Unfortunately will need to use gcc13 compilation

Option 1: Alpine
You can use an Alpine base image.
FROM rust:1-alpine

RUN apk add g++

In this case you'll immediately have access to GCC 13.
/ # gcc -v
gcc version 13.2.1 20231014 (Alpine 13.2.1_git20231014) 
/ # g++ -v
gcc version 13.2.1 20231014 (Alpine 13.2.1_git20231014)

Option 2: Install onto Debian
If you really want an image based on Debian Bookworm then you can install GCC 13 from source. It's a bit of a slog because the build takes a while.
FROM rust:1-bookworm AS builder

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
        build-essential \
        wget \
        libgmp-dev \
        libmpfr-dev \
        libmpc-dev

RUN wget -q https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-13.2.0/gcc-13.2.0.tar.gz
RUN tar -xf gcc-13.2.0.tar.gz && \
    cd gcc-13.2.0 && \
    ./contrib/download_prerequisites

# This will cross-compile using the existing GCC on the image.
RUN cd gcc-13.2.0 && \
    ./configure --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++ && \
    make -j$(nproc) && \
    make install

RUN update-alternatives \
        --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/local/bin/gcc 60 \
        --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/local/bin/g++ && \
    rm -rf gcc-13.2.0.tar.gz gcc-13.2.0 && \
    apt purge -y gcc cpp


For those who are trying to install gcc13 and g++13 in Debian 12, try to download the tar.gz file and extract it
https://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/releases/gcc-13.2.0/
Run the following commands inside of the extracted folder:
./contrib/download_prerequisites
./configure --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++
make -j3
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/local/bin/gcc 60 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/local/bin/g++

If you type g++ --version, it should look like this
g++ (GCC) 13.2.0
Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

